# why i can't get data from js function return from database in codeigniter

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

My js function is

```
function view_customerTOTable(){

    var name = $('#name').val();
    //alert(name);
    $.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'viewCustomerData',
    data: name,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('test'+data);

        var result = JSON.parse(data);

        var datas = [];

        for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
            datas.push('<tr id="op' + x + '">'
                    + '<td hidden="true">' + result[x].C_email + '</td>'
                    + '<td>' + result[x].C_clientint + '</td>'
                    + '<td align="center">' + result[x].C_status + '</td>'
                    + '<td align="center">' + result[x].C_clientcode + '</td>'
                    + '<td align="center">' + result[x].C_name + '</td>'
                    + '<td align="right">' + result[x].C_nic + '</td>'
                    + '<td align="center">'
                    + '<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="view">'

                    + '</td>'
                    + '</tr>');
        }

        $j('#bdy_customer_details').html(datas);
        //alert(data);

    },
    error: function(){
        alert('error');
    }
});



}
```

controller function is

```
function viewCustomerData(){
         $this->load->model('customer/customer_model');
    echo json_encode($this->customer_model->loadCustomerDetails());

}
```

the values return from this modle function

```
     function loadCustomerDetails(){
     //$query = $this->db->select('*')->from('customer');
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM customer where C_name = '{$_POST['name']}'";
     //$send = $query->mod_select();

     try {
        return $this->db->select($sql);
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        return $exc->getTraceAsString();
    }


 }
```

view page is

```
<table id="customer_details"  class="table table-bordered" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" width="100%"  >
                <thead>
                    <tr>

                        <td><font type="curlz MT Regular" color="black">Asset Type</font></td>
                        <td><font type="curlz MT Regular" color="black">Client Code</font></td>
                        <td><font type="curlz MT Regular" color="black">Contract No</font></td>
                        <td><font type="curlz MT Regular" color="black">Contract Name</font></td>
                        <td><font type="curlz MT Regular" color="black">Customer Name</font></td>
                        <td><font type="curlz MT Regular" color="black">NIC No.</font></td>
                        <td><font type="curlz MT Regular" color="black">View</font></td>
                        <!--<td>Remove</td>-->
                    </tr>
                <thead>
                <tbody id="bdy_customer_details" >   

                </tbody>
                 <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan="2"></td>
                            <td id="tdet1"></td>
                            <td id="tdet2"></td>
                            <td id="tdet3"></td>

                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
            </table>
```

i want to display those data in table. but i cant return data. in js function function move to success point. but json.parse point it not works

Comment: controller function is   function viewCustomerData(){
             $this->load->model('customer/customer_model');
        echo json_encode($this->customer_model->loadCustomerDetails());
            
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your controller action change below code. here in your code you are not return data from model. it return only test.

```
die(json_encode(array('result' => 'test')));

//as per updated question 

die(json_encode($this->customer_model->loadCustomerDetails()));
```

remove this header

```
header('Content-Type: application/json');
```

updated javascript code

```
    var result = JSON.parse(data);

    var datas = '';

    for (var x = 0; x < result.length; x++) {
        datas   = '<tr id="op' + x + '">'
                + '<td hidden="true">' + result[x].C_email + '</td>'
                + '<td>' + result[x].C_clientint + '</td>'
                + '<td align="center">' + result[x].C_status + '</td>'
                + '<td align="center">' + result[x].C_clientcode + '</td>'
                + '<td align="center">' + result[x].C_name + '</td>'
                + '<td align="right">' + result[x].C_nic + '</td>'
                + '<td align="center">'
                + '<input type="button" class="btn btn-warning" value="view">'

                + '</td>'
                + '</tr>';
       // if((result.length - 1) === x){
          $('#bdy_customer_details').append(datas);
        //}
    }
```

Comment: @bluefeet  at my work place chat system is blocked . so not able to chat with any one